# Conditional Formatting Access 2010 from code

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I don't know why the form don't show to me the format condition. I can only use it via code. I can't give formatting in the usual way. I call this function in `Form_Load`.

```
Function ControllaColori()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Formatta As FormatConditionI
    m_Anno = Anno
    m_Mese = Mese

    Forms("PresenzeOspite").Controls("tg1").FormatConditions.Delete

    Set Formatta = Forms("PresenzeOspite").Controls("tg1").FormatConditions.Add(acFieldValue, acEqual, "A")
    Set Formatta = Forms("PresenzeOspite").Controls("tg1").FormatConditions.Add(acFieldValue, acEqual, "P")
    Set Formatta = Forms("PresenzeOspite").Controls("tg1").FormatConditions.Add(acFieldValue, acEqual, "H")

    With Forms("PresenzeOspite").Controls("tg1").FormatConditions(0)
        .BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .FontBold = True
    End With

    With Forms("PresenzeOspite").Controls("tg1").FormatConditions(1)
        .BackColor = RGB(127, 255, 0)
        .FontBold = True
    End With

    With Forms("PresenzeOspite").Controls("tg1").FormatConditions(2)
        .BackColor = RGB(248, 248, 255)
        .FontBold = True
    End With

    Set Formatta = Forms("PresenzeOspite").Controls("tg1").FormatConditions.item(0)
    Set Formatta = Forms("PresenzeOspite").Controls("tg1").FormatConditions.item(1)
    Set Formatta = Forms("PresenzeOspite").Controls("tg1").FormatConditions.item(2)
    Set Formatta = Nothing
End Function
```

With this code `Forms("PresenzeOspite").Controls("tg1").FormatConditions.Delete` we can delete an existing condition but when we try to add a new condition with the previous code, in debug, I can obtain the condition from the object but it isn't displayed on the from in run-time

Comment: Could you give it a bit more verbiage? The current description is not 100% clear. What is the Form view? Why is this option unavailable to you?

Comment: With this code [code] Forms("PresenzeOspite").Controls("tg1").FormatConditions.Delete [/code] we can delete a existing condition but when we try to add a new condition with the previous code, in debug i can obtain the condition from the object but it isn't displayed on the from in runtime

Comment: Have you checked that the Background of the controls is NOT set to Transparent?